# Manipulate data inside a Promise and return it in a service function - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem where I can't assign the service return value into a variable. I have two controllers (AddProject and EditProject) and this function was in both of them, and I wanted to make a service to avoid repeating the code.

```
        ... 
        .service("UserService", function($http) {
        var allUsers;
        var usersPromise = $http.get("/users");
        usersPromise.then(
            function(response) {
                allUsers = response.data.map(function(user) {
                    user._lowername = user.name.toLowerCase();
                    return user;
                });
                console.log(allUsers) //It prints the object array 
                return allUsers;
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                return error;
            });

        this.AllUsers = function() {
            return allUsers;
        }
    })
```

And in my controller I have a variable:
(assume that all required injections were made)

```
self.AllUsers = UserService.AllUsers(); //it is undefined
```

I tried to use $q but it gets undefined too.

Comment: Where is this controller assignment happening? Are you sure the service promise has resolved before this assignment?

Comment: Can't you return the promise directly to the controllers, letting them handle the resolution ?

Comment: Because `var allUsers` is `undefined` when you call the method! You should return a promise.

Comment: @noKid but I will end up with the same repeated code, no? Cuz I will have a function for both controllers to manipulate the promise.

Comment: @estus but I need to return the object array.

Comment: You're not the first person who would prefer to return a value instead of a promise  - this object array just doesn't exist at the time when you call the function.

Comment: @NathanMartins, but the value you "need" *(want)* to return is `undefined` *(at that time)*. Ain't that the whole point of your question? And without a Promise *(or some different async approach, like callback, event, ...)* your calling code will have no idea when this has changed. That's the whole deal with Promises, to somehow solve/deal with this dilemma.

Comment: I posted a partial solution as an answer, could you comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution (I believe there is a best solution).

```
.service("UserService", function($http) {
    this.AllUsers = function() {
        return $http.get("/users");
    }
})
```

And I created a function outside the controllers:

```
function mapUsers(userResponse){
  return userResponse.data.map(function(user) {
      user._lowername = user.name.toLowerCase();
      return user;
  });
}
```

And in both controllers I call this:

```
UserService.AllUsers().then(function(response) {
            self.AllUsers = mapUsers(response);
        });
```

Comment: `mapUsers` helper function isn't really good. It is the job for `UserService`, it's its data and its responsibility to manipulate it, think of it as of MVC model. If both mapped and unmapped user arrays are used in the app, make it two methods instead of one.

Comment: I agree with estus. this way, every code that may call `UserService.allUsers()` kind of needs to know what' is behind that and needs to format the result by applying `mapUsers()`. I'd write it like that: `return $http.get("/users").then( response => response.data.map( user => (user._lowername = user.name.toLowerCase(), user) ) )` The only thing that has now changed, compared to your original attempt, is that the calling code recieves a `Promise<allUsers>` instead of `allUsers`

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for using promises is to deal with asynchronous calls (like you $http.get()), but you you seem to be trying to use it in a synchronous way. Your service should just return the promise, then your controller should call it and do what it needs to when it resolves:

```
.service("UserService", function($http) {
    var allUsers;
    var usersPromise = $http.get("/users");
    usersPromise.then(
            function(response) {
                allUsers = response.data.map(function(user) {
                    user._lowername = user.name.toLowerCase();
                    return user;
                });
                console.log(allUsers) //It prints the object array
                return allUsers;
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                return error;
            });

    this.AllUsers = function() {
        return usersPromise;
    };
});
```

....

```
UserService.AllUsers().then(function(users) {
    self.AllUsers = users;
});
```

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that all calls to AllUsers() will execute a new server call. Based on the the question, it seems that the OP only wanted to make that call once.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to return self-filling array from asynchronous function that will be filled with values later:

```
    ... 
    .service("UserService", function($http) {
    var allUsers = [];
    var usersPromise = $http.get("/users");
    usersPromise.then(
        function(response) {
            var result = response.data.map(function(user) {
                user._lowername = user.name.toLowerCase();
                return user;
            });
            angular.copy(allUsers, result);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return error;
        });

    this.AllUsers = function() {
        return allUsers;
    }
})
```

`angular.copy` doesn't change the reference to the array when filling it, the returned empty array is updated automatically in view.

This trick is particularly used in ngResource `$resource`.

Comment: I will check this out.